# Could not call the factory method using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-factory

I am getting some error while trying to call the factory method using Angular.js. I am explaining my code below.

> Error:

```
TypeError: focusInputField.hoverIn is not a function
```

My controller side code is given below.

```
var customerNew=angular.module('Spesh');
customerNew.controller('adminCustomerNewController',function($http,$state,$scope,$window,$timeout,Upload,focusInputField){
  $scope.hoverIn=function(id){
      focusInputField.hoverIn(id);
  }
  $scope.hoverOut=function(id){
    focusInputField.hoverOut(id);
  }
})
customerNew.factory('focusInputField',function($timeout, $window) {
    return{
        borderColor:function(id){
             $timeout(function() {
                 var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
                 if(element){
                      element.focus();
                      element.style.borderColor = "red";
                 }
             });
        },
        clearBorderColor:function(id){
            $timeout(function() {
                var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
                 if(element){
                     element.style.borderColor = "#cccccc";
                 }
            });
        },
    hoverIn:function(id){
      $timeout(function() {
        var ids='#'+id;
        $(ids).css("cursor","pointer");
        $(ids).animate({width: "100px"}, 'slow');
      });
    },
    hoverOut:function(id){
      $timeout(function() {
        var ids='#'+id;
        $(ids).animate({width: "32px"}, 'slow');
      });
    }
    };
});
```

Here I am getting error while calling both the function (`i.e-hoverIn,hoverOut`). Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Aside from your problem, the goal of AngularJS is to not edit the DOM elements. What you are doing is a bad practice. You should think about using `ng-class` or `ng-style`

Comment: I need to resolve this error first.

Comment: i created a plnkr seems to be working fine https://plnkr.co/edit/R0c53a8T3t71Txd7uj22?p=preview

Comment: @sachilaranawaka : Yes,but in my side its not working.

Comment: is your factory in separate js fiie

Comment: @sachilaranawaka : No,its in same file

Comment: @sachilaranawaka : I solved it using a new factory method. THank you.

Comment: @subhra create plnkr of your code. So, someone will able to debug it.

Comment: @subhra no prob bro